# What nested patterns are valid in dafny?

Tags: design-patterns, nested, dafny

```
This may be a limitation or a bug either in dafny or in my understanding.
```

Any help understanding this much appreciated.

The following dafny function verifies

```
datatype Tree<T> = Leaf(data: T)
                 | Node(left: Tree<T>, right: Tree<T>)
 function   treetree(t: Tree<Color>) : string 
 {
     match t
         case Leaf(_) => "zero"
         case Node(Node(_,_),_) => "two"
         case Node(Leaf(_),_) => "one"
 }
```

Whereas then next function fails:

```
function   treelist(t: Tree<List<string>>) : string 
 {
     match t
         case Leaf(Nil) => "zero"
         case Leaf(Cons(_,_)) => "list"
         case Node(_,_) => "two"
         
 }
```

The error states that "member Leaf appears in more than one case" which I know is correct but as member Node appears in more than one case in the previous valid function I am not sure when this error actually applies.

Additional detail

```
datatype Color = Red | Blue |  Named(name: string)
datatype Tree<T> = Leaf(data: T)
                 | Node(left: Tree<T>, right: Tree<T>)
```

Plus I noticed that the following verifies

```
function   leaflist(t: Tree<List<string>>) : string 
 {
     match t
         case Leaf(Nil) => "zero"
         case Leaf(Cons(_,_)) => "list"
         case Node(Node(_,_),_) => "two"
         case Node(Leaf(_),_) => "one"
 }
```

Comment: can you show the complete code including your definition of `List`?

Comment: and the definition of `Color`? also, what version of Dafny are you using? I made a version of your example on my machine by filling in reasonable definitions of `List` and `Color`, and it worked without errors.

Comment: I edited the question to add the requested detail.

Comment: I still don't see the definition of `List`. And I still wonder what version of Dafny you're using. And it still works on my machine :)

Comment: ok, I got it to fail on rise4fun: https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/WQrde but the problem is fixed in master. so you can either build from source or ask Rustan to cut a release on github